# tor-browser-bundle vs tbb tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently separate tags for "tor-browser-bundle" and "tbb". I've edited posts with the *tbb* tag to reference *tor-browser-buldle* instead.

Can "tbb" be merged into "tor-browser-bundle" by somebody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a synonym proposal for these two tags [on the tag page](https://tor.stackexchange.com/tags/tor-browser-bundle/synonyms). When a net total of 4 users vote for the synonym it will be automatically approved. Users who have more than 5 reputation points earned related to that tag can vote on the proposal.

Comment: Looks like I was just the fourth vote - it's set!